# Haskell way to join [IO String] into IO String

Tags: haskell, io, monads

my goal is to write Haskell function which reads N lines from input and joins them in one string. Below is the first attempt:

```
readNLines :: Int -> IO String
readNLines n = do
  let rows = replicate n getLine
  let rowsAsString = foldl ++ [] rows 
  return rowsAsString
```

Here haskell complaints on `foldl`:

> Couldn't match expected type `[a]'
>   against inferred type`(a1 -> b -> a1)
>   -> a1 -> [b] -> a1'

As I understand type of rows is `[IO String]`, is it possible some how join such list in a single `IO String`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're looking for [`sequence :: (Monad m) => [m a] -> m [a]`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.1/html/libraries/base-4.3.0.0/Control-Monad.html#v:sequence).

(Plus [`liftM :: Monad m => (a1 -> r) -> m a1 -> m r`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.1/html/libraries/base-4.3.0.0/Control-Monad.html#v:liftM) and [`unlines :: [String] -> String`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.1/html/libraries/base-4.3.0.0/Data-List.html#v:unlines), probably.)

Answer (score 6):

Besides what ephemient points out, I think you have a syntax issue: The way you're using the `++` operator makes it look like you are trying to invoke the `++` operator with operands `foldl` and `[]`. Put the `++` operator in parentheses to make your intent clear:

```
foldl (++) [] rows
```

Comment: Ah yes, that is the immediate cause of the typecheck error… that I ignored, since even after OP fixes that they've still got another problem.

Comment: Should also note that `foldl (++) []` is the same as `concat`.

Answer (score 5):

The functions you are looking for is is `sequence`, however it should be noted that

```
sequence (replicate n f)
```

is the same as

```
replicateM n f
```

And `foldl (++) []` is equivalent to `concat`. So your function is:

```
readNLines n = liftM concat (replicateM n getLine)
```

Alternatively if you want to preserve line breaks:

```
readNLines n = liftM unlines (replicateM n getLine)
```

Comment: `concat` is `foldr (++) []`, not `foldl`: works fine on infinite streams of lists.  You're missing `n` as an argument to `replicateM` in your later examples there, too.  But yes, those are good points.

Comment: @ephemient, thanks for the heads up, I fixed the error with n, and yes `concat` is really `foldr (++) []`, what I mean was that he wrote `foldl (++) []` wich is equivalent to `concat`, although as you mention, `concat` is actually better since it works on infinite streams.

Answer (score 1):

The shortest answer I can come up with is:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad

readNLines :: Int -> IO String
readNLines n = concat <$> replicateM n getLine
```

Answer (score 0):

`replicate` returns a list of `IO String` actions.  In order to perform these actions, they need to be run in the IO monad.  So you don't want to join an array of IO actions, but rather run them all in sequence and return the result.

Here's what I would do

```
readNLines :: Int -> IO String
readNLines n = do
  lines <- replicateM n getLine
  return $ concat lines
```

Or, in applicative style:

```
import Control.Applicative

readNLines :: Int -> IO String
readNLines n = concat <$> replicateM n getLine
```

Both of these use the monadic replicate (replicateM), which evaluates a list of monadic values in sequence, rather than simply returning a list of actions